# Saving GPS Image Direction tag in android

Tags: android, exif

How do I save GPS_IMG_DIRECTION tag to an image in android?
I have check the following exifinterface link, but it does not seem to have GPS_IMG_DIRECTION.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

I have tried to add customtag by using this:

```
exifTags.setAttribute("TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION", "123");
                    exifTags.setAttribute("TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION_REF", "M");
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I also tried to use the hexadecimal value of the tag by :

```
 exifTags.setAttribute("0x0011", "123");
```

But this too doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION` is a Java constant. The underlying EXIF attribute is `GPSImgDirection`. Also, for an azimuth of 45.5°, the value should be formatted as `"4550/100"`. The resulting that worked for me is:

```
val exif = ExifInterface(file)
val imageDirectionAsString = (imageDirection * 100).roundToInt().toString() + "/100"
exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION, imageDirectionAsString)
```

Comment: Side question: Do you know if TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION_REF should be specified when adding the direction angle to the EXIF metadata. And if yes, should 0 be added, because representing North?

Answer (score 0):

Google's ExifInterface supported very limited number of tags. You need to add this tag by yourself.
For this purpose you may look at

http://rcs34-android.blogspot.ru/2012/09/exif-metadata-handler-for-android-pure.html 
https://code.google.com/p/exif-driver/source/browse/src/rcs34/android/libs/ExifDriver/